# SOQL retrieve limited?

Tags: apex, java, wsdl2apex, partner-wsdl, governorlimits

I'm doing an integration using Partner WSDL.

When I try to retrieve more than 15 Leads, it's return NullPointerException and I have 43 Leads.
When I try to retieve all my Contacts, it's just return 23 and I have 43 Contacts.

Important, Contacts doesn't do any error, but Leads do.
Someone can explain?

Update:

I created an Object Lead with all data a Lead in SF can have.

```
Lead lead = new Lead();
        Lead[] resultL = null;

        query = connection.query("SELECT" + " Id," + "FirstName," + " LastName," + " Company" + " FROM Lead"
                + " WHERE Company != NULL" + " ORDER BY CreatedDate" + " DESC");

        resultL = lead.queryLeads(connection, query);
```

The same thing for Contacts.

Comment: Most likely, it's a bug in your code. You certainly *should* be able to get up to 2,000 records per query()/queryMore() (depending on number of fields selected), and SOQL should *not* be returning a NullPointerException. Can you please add the relevant code you're using where you're getting the error?

Comment: I'll update the question with a piece of code

Comment: Can you show the line of code that corresponds to the NullPointerException? At a guess it would be somewhere inside your `queryLeads` method. Is it expecting a certain field that isn't being populated by the SOQL?

Comment: The code pass the `lead.setId(sobj[j].getId());`
then go to the `lead.setFirstName(sobj[j].getField("FirstName").toString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `lead.setFirstName(sobj[j].getField("FirstName").toString());`

The Lead FirstName field is not required. As such, it will return as null via the API if it is not defined.

You will need to check if it is null before attempting to convert it to a string.

---

It is likely that you are only getting a subset of records back for the SOQL query as the API user that the session belongs to doesn't have access to all the records in question.

Comment: The Contact doesn't show `NullPointerException`

Comment: But now I saw, for the Lead, just LastName and Company is required.

Comment: `sobj[j].getField("FirstName")` will be returning null. The `NullPointerException` will be coming from calling `toString()` on that null.
Try running the same SOQL query in the developer console and checking for Leads with no FirstName

Comment: @JulioC.Boll Yes, I got mixed up. I meant that it isn't a required field on Lead. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: And do you know why I'm just retrieving 23 of 43 Contact ? Because the query clause is just the same (without the Company field) and it doesn't show any Exception or Error

Comment: @JulioC.Boll The user running the SOQL query via the API may not have access to all the Contacts in question. Get the ID of one of the records that aren't appearing in the SOQL results and try directly accessing that record. You will likely get a permission error.